# ¿Cómo puedo definir las funciones del siguiente código para evitar que sea redundante?

Tags: python, funciones

Trato de hacer que un programa me diga y calcule la cantidad de elementos de una construcción a partir de un par de datos que introduzca el usuario. Pero el problema me surge al querer evitar repetir el mismo código tres veces (1.- columnas, 2.- trabes y 3.- losas de techo + losa de piso):

```
cemento, arena, grava, agua, cal = 350, 0.56, 0.84, 180, 68 #Estos datos son por default



def main():
    
    pisos=int(input('\n¿Cuántos pisos tiene su estructura?: '))
    if pisos > 0:
        print('\n########### Columnas ###########')
        columnas=int(input(f'\nInserte la cantidad de columnas totales de la estructura: '))
        if columnas > 2:
            altura=float(input('Ingrese la altura de su columna: '))
            longitud=float(input('Ingrese la longitud de su columna: '))
            profundidad=float(input('Ingrese la profundidad de su columna: '))


            volumen_columna=altura*longitud*profundidad

            peso_individual_columna_cemento=((volumen_columna*cemento)*1.05)
            cantidad_bolsas=(peso_individual_columna_cemento/50)
            peso_individual_columna_arena=(volumen_columna*arena)
            peso_individual_columna_grava=(volumen_columna*grava)
            peso_individual_columna_agua=(volumen_columna*agua)
            peso_individual_columna_cal=(volumen_columna*cal)
            
            suma_total_elementos_columna=(peso_individual_columna_cemento+peso_individual_columna_arena+peso_individual_columna_grava+peso_individual_columna_agua+peso_individual_columna_cal)

            peso_columnas_cemento=(peso_individual_columna_cemento*columnas)

            cantidad_de_bolas_totales=(peso_individual_columna_cemento*columnas)/50
            peso_columnas_arena=(peso_individual_columna_arena*columnas)
            peso_columnas_grava=(peso_individual_columna_grava*columnas)
            peso_columnas_agua=(peso_individual_columna_agua*columnas)
            peso_columnas_cal=(peso_individual_columna_cal*columnas)
            peso_total_columnas=(suma_total_elementos_columna*columnas)

            


            print(f'\nVolúmen de cada columna es de ' "{0:.4f}".format(volumen_columna) + ' m³')
            print(f'\nPeso individual de cemento de cada columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_individual_columna_cemento) + ' kg/m³' + ', o sea, ocupas ' + "{0:.1f}".format(cantidad_bolsas) + ' bolsas de cemento')
            print(f'Peso individual de arena de cada columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_individual_columna_arena) + ' kg/m³')
            print(f'Peso individual de grava de cada columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_individual_columna_grava) + ' kg/m³')
            print(f'Peso individual de agua de cada columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_individual_columna_agua) + ' lts/m³')
            print(f'Peso individual de cal de cada columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_individual_columna_cal) + ' kg/m³')



            print(f'\nPeso total de materiales de la columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(suma_total_elementos_columna) + ' kg/m³')

            print(f'\nLa cantidad de cemento que necesitas por las {columnas} columnas ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_columnas_cemento) + ' kg' + ', o sea, ocupas ' + "{0:.1f}".format(cantidad_de_bolas_totales) + ' bolsas de cemento')
            print(f'La cantidad de arena que necesitas por las {columnas} columnas ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_columnas_arena) + ' kg')
            print(f'La cantidad de grava que necesitas por las {columnas} columnas ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_columnas_grava) + ' kg')
            print(f'La cantidad de agua que necesitas por las {columnas} columnas ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_columnas_agua) + ' lts')
            print(f'La cantidad de cal que necesitas por las {columnas} columnas ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_columnas_cal) + ' kg')

            print(f'\nEl peso total de las {columnas} columnas es: ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_total_columnas) + ' kg')
            
        elif columnas == 1 or columnas == 2:
            print(f'¿Cómo va a tener {columnas} columna el edificio? no digas mamadas')
        else:
            print(f'{op}')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Me falla mucho implementar la función `def()` a la hora de programar, así que, ¿cómo puedo implementar la función `def()` en el código anterior para no repetir tres veces los mismos datos?

Código completo:

```
from random import choice

def suma_total(elementos):

    return suma_total



def suma_elementos():
    return suma_elementos

chistes=['A ver mijo, no mames', 
    'Nop', 
    '¿Acaso quieres que el universo explote?', 
    'No se puede!', 
    'Ste men xd', 
    'Oye, tranquilo viej@!', 'Oh shit, that's an illegal move!']
op=choice(chistes)




cemento, arena, grava, agua, cal = 350, 0.56, 0.84, 180, 68



def main():
    
    pisos=int(input('\n¿Cuántos pisos tiene su estructura?: '))
    if pisos > 0:
        print('\n########### Columnas ###########')
        columnas=int(input(f'\nInserte la cantidad de columnas totales de la estructura: '))
        if columnas > 2:
            altura=float(input('Ingrese la altura de su columna: '))
            longitud=float(input('Ingrese la longitud de su columna: '))
            profundidad=float(input('Ingrese la profundidad de su columna: '))


            volumen_columna=altura*longitud*profundidad

            peso_individual_columna_cemento=((volumen_columna*cemento)*1.05)
            cantidad_bolsas=(peso_individual_columna_cemento/50)
            peso_individual_columna_arena=(volumen_columna*arena)
            peso_individual_columna_grava=(volumen_columna*grava)
            peso_individual_columna_agua=(volumen_columna*agua)
            peso_individual_columna_cal=(volumen_columna*cal)
            
            suma_total_elementos_columna=(peso_individual_columna_cemento+peso_individual_columna_arena+peso_individual_columna_grava+peso_individual_columna_agua+peso_individual_columna_cal)

            peso_columnas_cemento=(peso_individual_columna_cemento*columnas)

            cantidad_de_bolas_totales=(peso_individual_columna_cemento*columnas)/50
            peso_columnas_arena=(peso_individual_columna_arena*columnas)
            peso_columnas_grava=(peso_individual_columna_grava*columnas)
            peso_columnas_agua=(peso_individual_columna_agua*columnas)
            peso_columnas_cal=(peso_individual_columna_cal*columnas)
            peso_total_columnas=(suma_total_elementos_columna*columnas)

            


            print(f'\nVolúmen de cada columna es de ' "{0:.4f}".format(volumen_columna) + ' m³')
            print(f'\nPeso individual de cemento de cada columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_individual_columna_cemento) + ' kg/m³' + ', o sea, ocupas ' + "{0:.1f}".format(cantidad_bolsas) + ' bolsas de cemento')
            print(f'Peso individual de arena de cada columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_individual_columna_arena) + ' kg/m³')
            print(f'Peso individual de grava de cada columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_individual_columna_grava) + ' kg/m³')
            print(f'Peso individual de agua de cada columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_individual_columna_agua) + ' lts/m³')
            print(f'Peso individual de cal de cada columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_individual_columna_cal) + ' kg/m³')



            print(f'\nPeso total de materiales de la columna ' "{0:.4f}".format(suma_total_elementos_columna) + ' kg/m³')

            print(f'\nLa cantidad de cemento que necesitas por las {columnas} columnas ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_columnas_cemento) + ' kg' + ', o sea, ocupas ' + "{0:.1f}".format(cantidad_de_bolas_totales) + ' bolsas de cemento')
            print(f'La cantidad de arena que necesitas por las {columnas} columnas ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_columnas_arena) + ' kg')
            print(f'La cantidad de grava que necesitas por las {columnas} columnas ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_columnas_grava) + ' kg')
            print(f'La cantidad de agua que necesitas por las {columnas} columnas ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_columnas_agua) + ' lts')
            print(f'La cantidad de cal que necesitas por las {columnas} columnas ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_columnas_cal) + ' kg')

            print(f'\nEl peso total de las {columnas} columnas es: ' "{0:.4f}".format(peso_total_columnas) + ' kg')
            
        elif columnas == 1 or columnas == 2:
            print(f'¿Cómo va a tener {columnas} columna el edificio? no digas mamadas')
        else:
            print(f'{op}')

        print('\n########### Trabes ###########')
        trabes=int(input(f'\nInserte la cantidad de trabes totales de la estructura: '))
        if trabes > 2:
            altura=float(input('Ingrese la altura de su trabe: '))
            longitud=float(input('Ingrese la longitud de su trabe: '))
            profundidad=float(input('Ingrese la profundidad de su trabe: '))
        elif trabes == 1 or trabes == 2:
            print(f'¿Cómo va a tener {trabes} trabe el edificio? no digas mamadas')
        else:
            print(f'{op}')

        losas=pisos+1 #Se le añade el +1 por la losa de entre piso, la cantidad de losas de techo + la losa de piso
                 
    else:
        print(f'{op}')





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Agradezco mucho que se hayan tomado su tiempo para leer esto, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El manejo de los cálculos se puede simplificar vía diccionarios.

Para cada cosa que quieras construir (columna, trabas o losas) requiere una mezcla de un mismo conjunto de materiales. Suponiendo que las proporciones son distintas para cada estructura, definire un diccionario para cada una de ellas:

```
mat_columna = dict(
    cemento=350 * 1.05,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=180,
    cal=68) # Estos datos son por default
mat_traba = dict(
    cemento=360,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=200,
    cal=68) # Estos datos son por default
mat_losa = dict(
    cemento=351,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=180,
    cal=68) # Estos datos son por default
```

Asi, por ejemplo,

```
mat_columna["agua"]
```

me da la cantidad de agua requerida para un m3 de columna.

Ahora lo que necesito es una función que dado un volumen (de losa, columna o traba), me diga cuanto material necesito para ello. El material total lo calculara el llamante multiplicando por el número de unidades (columnas, losas, o trabas).

Esta función

```
def calculo(materiales, volumen):
    peso_individual = {key: volumen * value for key, value in materiales.items()}
    bolsas = (peso_individual["cemento"] / 50)
    return peso_individual, bolsas
```

calcula lo materiales necesarios para una mezcla del volumen indicado.

La función retorna un diccionario con los materiales calculados y el número de bolsas de cemento (50 kgs) necesarias.

La línea

```
peso_individual = {key: volumen * value for key, value in materiales.items()}
```

usa compresión de diccionarios (crea un diccionario), y es equivalente a

```
for key, value in materiales.items():
    peso_individual[key] = volumen * materiales[key]
```

El mismo concepto se puede aplicar para simplificar la impresión de los resultados, parametrizando adecuadamente los mensajes.

**Ejemplo**

```
mat_columnas = dict(
    cemento=350,
    arena=0.56,
    grava=0.84,
    agua=180,
    cal=68) # Estos datos son por default

def calculo(materiales, volumen):
    peso_individual = {key: volumen * value for key, value in materiales.items()}
    bolsas = (peso_individual["cemento"] / 50)
    return peso_individual, bolsas

pesos, bolsas = calculo(mat_columnas, 1*4*2)
print (pesos, bolsas)
```

produce:

```
{'cemento': 2800, 'arena': 4.48, 'grava': 6.72, 'agua': 1440, 'cal': 544} 56.0
```

Comment: Hay una cosa que no entiendo o no logré entender, para definir los materiales que están en .items tengo que agregar los detalles o sustituir?

Comment: No es necesario agregar nada. Las cantidades de materiales se definen al inicializar los diccionarios. Si todos los elementos usan la misma proporción de materiales, puedes quedarte con uno solo (diccionario). ¿Era eso?

Comment: Estoy probando el código que me has explicado y me arroja esto al definir materiales: **AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'**

Comment: Pero si no los defino me arroja esto: **NameError: name 'materiales' is not defined**

Comment: Agregué un ejemplo para mejor comprensión.

Comment: ¿Para iterar `mat_columnas`, `mat_trabes` y `mat_losas` cómo lo implemento en el código sin que me arroje **AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'**?

Comment: Añadí esta lista: `elementos={1: 'mat_columnas', 2: 'mat_trabes', 3: 'mat_losas'}` luego el ciclo for: `for i in elementos.values():
    pesos, bolsas = calculo(i, 4*0.8*0.8)
    print (pesos, bolsas)`

Comment: mat_columnas es un diccionario, no un string. Mejor actualiza tu pregunta con el nuevo código que has intentando para entender mejor.